# Promise doesn't reject

Tags: javascript, promise

Here is the code:

```
await fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    login: name,
    password: pass
  }),
})
.then(async() => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('Login', name)
})
.catch(err => alert(err));
```

When I try to intentionally make a mistake in order to test the logging process, I get the error in the "Network" tab of my browser, but my website thinks that everything is fine and it executes the `.then()` code, even though it obviously shouldn't do that, because the Promise is rejected (it says POST http://localhost:3000/login 400 (Bad Request) in the console).

I tried a different code

```
.then(async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('Login', name) 
  }, (reason) => 
  alert(reason)
);
```

But it too doesn't work the way I want, it should execute this part `(reason) => alert(reason))`.

What's the solution?

Comment: `fetch` doesn't reject its promise on HTTP errors, only network-level errors. (I think it's a bit of an API footgun, to be blunt.) You need to check `ok` on the response object you receive as the fulfillment value of the initial promise. I wrote it up [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: Side note: Combining `async`/`await` with `.then`/`.catch` tends to get pretty confusing, best to use one or the other, not both. Example of fixing both: https://pastebin.com/pgAfj38D